# Creating dynamic arrays in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, dynamic

Quite new to Powershell, so I hope it is not a dumb question ;)

I am trying to read EXIT STATUS codes from a large amount of text (Held in an array called $MainArray).

The text has many occurrences of the words ERROR STATUS followed by a number, like:

Random text random text **EXIT STATUS 0** random text random text 
Random text **EXIT STATUS 123** random text random text random text 
**EXIT STATUS 5** random text random text random text random text 
etc.

Some EXIT STATUS followed by a number have many occurrences in the file and doubles need to be removed

I collect these EXIT STATUS codes, and put them in an array, remove the doubles (So far no problem), but I want to create NEW ARRAYs from the entries I have found.

To do this, I remove the spaces and replace them with _ so the array contains:

...
**EXIT_STATUS_0**
**EXIT_STATUS_123**
**EXIT_STATUS_5**
...

The dynamic code I would like to be executed would be like:

```
...
$EXIT_STATUS_0 = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
$EXIT_STATUS_123 = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
$EXIT_STATUS_5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
...
```

But I don't know how to generate the code that would do that for me :(

I hope you are able to help me with this... Hope my ramblings make sense ;)

This is what I got:

```
...
While ($MainCounter -le $MainArray.count)
{
    $StringToMatch = 'EXIT STATUS (\d{1,4})'
    If ($MainArray[$MainCounter] -match $StringToMatch)
    {
        $FoundStatusCodeArray += $Matches[0]

        $ExitStatusArray += $MainArray[$MainCounter]    
        $ExitStatusCounter ++
    }
    $MainCounter ++
}

$FoundStatusCodeArray = $FoundStatusCodeArray|Select-Object -Unique

ForEach ($FoundStatus in $FoundStatusCodeArray)
{   
    $FoundStatus = $FoundStatus.Replace(" ", "_")

    #Create all empty arrays here from the array
    foreach (blah)
    {   
       ?????? = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
    }

    #Code that fills the unknown number of generated arrays
    ?????

}
```

Sample of the text file is for instance:

```
1485202557 1 65604 4 appxxx 1792308 1792246 0 appxxx nbpem CLIENT APPxxx  POLICY dc1_vm_prod_df_2100_media1  SCHED 01_df  EXIT STATUS 0 (the requested operation was successfully completed) VBRF 1 0
1485202564 1 4 4 appxxx 1792278 1792188 0 appxxx bptm successfully wrote backup id appxxx_1485202103, copy 1, fragment 2, 10616729 Kbytes at 513232.573 Kbytes/sec
1485202565 1 33412 4 appxxx 1792278 1792188 0 appxxx bptm StorageServer=PureDisk:appxxx; Report=PDDO Stats for (appxxx): scanned: 61853747 KB, CR sent: 547527 KB, CR sent over FC: 0 KB, dedup: 99.1%, cache disabled
1485202566 1 65604 4 appxxx 1792278 1792188 0 appxxx nbpem CLIENT appxxx  POLICY dc1_vm_ota_df_2100_media3  SCHED 01_df  EXIT STATUS 0 (the requested operation was successfully completed) VBRF 1 0
```

Complex explanation, but this is what I need as an ultimate goal:

I need to find ALL lines that belong to a job (Here indicated by a process ID 1792278) that are dispersed randomly in the text file that produced a certain EXIT STATUS (0 in this example)

The EXIT STATUS 0 is only produced once for job id 1792278, and I need to find all the lines that relate to this job ID

Comment: Wait. You have a text containing multiple error codes. What do you want to do with them? I mean, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Where is the data in your `$MainArray` source coming from? Not to poke holes in your code but this seems like a difficult way to parse code coming from another process...

Comment: Why do you want to put these codes in arrays?  Are you trying to group the preceeding text based on the ExitStatus?

Comment: The text is pulled from a Linux server (The Powershell is executed from my workstation). My ultimate goal (Quite complex to explan, sorry!) is to parse through the text several times, to collect the lines that are related to that STATUS code. A sample of the text is just added to the original post with some extra info.

Comment: @Fredster from the sounds of things your input from the Linux server is formatted like one big string. To begin with, I would try splitting the text on line feeds (as Linux standard is to use line feeds for new-line separators instead of the Windows standard which are carriage return and **then** line feeds) to get them into separate lines and work from there. This is fairly attainable with a ForEach-Object script that loops through the String array and parses the EXIT STATUS codes that you've mentioned. I'll come back to this tomorrow and provide an answer.

Comment: @FoxDeploy The lines are actually nicely split and seperated in $MainArray... When I type $MainArray[somenumber] I get a nice single line out the total array

Comment: Oh @FoxDeploy got my ultimate goal perfectly:
I am trying to group the preceding text based on the EXIT STATUS by searching for the lines with a processID that generated the EXIT STATUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating variables with dynamic names is a terrible idea - how are you going to keep track of them?

In 9 out of 10 cases, you're better off with a Hashtable.

It's not entirely clear from the question exactly *what* you want to populate these dynamically generated arrays with, but in the following I'm going to assume that you want all the lines containing a specific status code linked back to that status code:

```
# Create an empty hashtable:
$StatusTable = @{}

# Pipe your array to `Select-String` and look for a pattern to match EXIT STATUS [number]
$MainArray |Select-String -Pattern '\bEXIT STATUS \d+\b' -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {
    foreach($StatusMatch in $_.Matches){
        # Check if a hashtable key already exist for the status code string
        if($StatusTable.ContainsKey($StatusMatch.Value)){
            # Already exists, add line to existing array
            $StatusTable[$StatusMatch.Value] += $_.Line
        } else {
            # Doesn't exist yet, create key by assigning 1-item array
            $StatusTable[$StatusMatch.Value] = @($_.Line)
        }
    }
}
```

Now all your data is available in the hashtable `$StatusTable`, and you can access your data by status code:

```
$StatusTable['EXIT STATUS 0']
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, wow that has *REALLY* helped me a great deal! I never thought of using hashtables instead of arrays... 

This does EXACTLY what I need to continue! Thanks!